# Do we always have particle-hole symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, superconductivity, topology

If we write the BdG equation for any model, and double the degrees of freedom (e.g. 4N*4N matrix for a N site chain), then we are guaranteed the particle-hole symmetry. Is there any constraints to do this procedure for every model? Thanks!

PS: in topology class of BdG classes, this corresponds to class D, which is of the least symmetry in the BdG class.

Comment: This question is very tacit as it stands. Could you elaborate by adding some details?

Comment: Yes, BCS Hamiltonians always have this symmetry.

Comment: The particle-hole symmetry is built in automatically by the doubling of degrees of freedom in order to diagonalize the mean-field Hamiltonian. It is an exact symmetry of any BdG Hamiltonian.

Comment: thanks, do we need some condition to write the BdG Hamiltonian, e.g. superconductivity?